# Unable to access the DOM which I passed as a string. How to do it by using external function as I defined in the code?

Tags: javascript, json, bootstrap-4, styles, web-frontend

I want to add an event to the "Important" link i.e. When One user clicks the "Important" link, the corresponding card color should be changed and saved in the localstorage but, when I am accessing that DOM file which I passed as a string, I am unable to do it. For e.g. - I can't access to `document.getElementsByClassName("noteCard")` in function `markNotes(index)`. But at the same time
`console.log("Color is not applied")` executes successfully. If I am adding `document.body.style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";` then also body color changes accordingly, but the I want to change the background color of the card with class "noteCard" only. I am really stuck with it.

**Below is my **HTML** code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Magic Notes</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Customstyle.css">

</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Magic Notes</a>
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.facebook.com/balabhadra.chand/" target="_blank">About me</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="searchTitle" type="search" placeholder="Search by title" aria-label="Search">
            </form>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="searchTxt" type="search" placeholder="Search text" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0 " id="searchBtn" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <h1 class="heading">It's all about magic !!!</h1>
    <div class="card" style="width: 1000px;">

        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text">Add a title to your note</textarea></span>
            </div>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="addTitle" aria-label="With textarea"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="card-body">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Write your Note</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="addTxt" rows="3"></textarea>
                </div>
            </form>

            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="addBtn">ADD NOTE</button>
        </div>

    </div>
    <hr>
    <h5>Your Notes</h5>
    <hr>
    <div id="notes" class="row container-fluid"></div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="myscript.js"></script>
</body>
```

**Here is my JavaScript code**

```
console.log('MagicNotes')
showNotes();

let addBtn = document.getElementById("addBtn");
addBtn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    let addTxt = document.getElementById("addTxt");
    let addTitle = document.getElementById("addTitle");
    let notes = localStorage.getItem("notes");
    if (notes != null) {
        notesObj = JSON.parse(notes);
    } else {
        notesObj = [];
    }
    let myObj = {
        title: addTitle.value,
        text: addTxt.value
    }
    notesObj.push(myObj)
    localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notesObj));
    addTxt.value = "";
    addTitle.value = "";
    showNotes();
});

function showNotes() {
    let notes = localStorage.getItem("notes");
    if (notes != null) {
        notesObj = JSON.parse(notes);
    } else {
        notesObj = [];
    }
    let html = "";
    notesObj.forEach(function(element, index) {
        html += `<div class="noteCard card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Title: ${element.title}</h5>
          
          <p class="card-text">${element.text}</p>
          <a href="#" id="${index}"onclick="deleteNotes(this.id)" class="card-link" >Delete Note</a>
          <a href="#" id="${index}"onclick="markNotes(this.id)"class="card-link">Important</a>
        </div>
      </div>`;

    });
    let notesElem = document.getElementById("notes");
    if (notesObj.length != 0) {
        notesElem.innerHTML = html;
    } else {
        notesElem.innerHTML = `Please add a note by clicking "ADD NOTE"`;
    }
}

function deleteNotes(index) {
    let notes = localStorage.getItem("notes");
    if (notes != null) {
        notesObj = JSON.parse(notes);
    } else {
        notesObj = [];
    }
    notesObj.splice(index, 1);
    localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notesObj));
    showNotes();
}

function markNotes(index) {
    let notes = localStorage.getItem("notes");
    if (notes != null) {
        notesObj = JSON.parse(notes);
    } else {
        notesObj = [];
    }
    document.getElementsByClassName("noteCard").style.color = "lightblue";
    console.log("Color is not applied")
    localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notesObj));
    showNotes();
}

let searchText = document.getElementById('searchTxt');
searchText.addEventListener("input", function(txt) {

    let inputVal = searchText.value.toLowerCase();
    // console.log('Input event fired!', inputVal);
    let noteCards = document.getElementsByClassName('noteCard');
    Array.from(noteCards).forEach(function(element) {
        let cardTxt = element.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerText;
        if (cardTxt.includes(inputVal)) {
            element.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            element.style.display = "none";
        }
        // console.log(cardTxt);
    })
})
let searchTitle = document.getElementById('searchTitle');
searchTitle.addEventListener("input", function(title) {

    let inputValTitle = searchTitle.value.toLowerCase();
    let noteCardsTitle = document.getElementsByClassName('noteCard');
    Array.from(noteCardsTitle).forEach(function(element) {
        let cardTitle = element.getElementsByTagName("h5")[0].innerText;
        if (cardTitle.includes(inputValTitle)) {
            element.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            element.style.display = "none";
        }
        // console.log(cardTitle);
    })
})
```

Comment: Since you're including jQuery, why don't you use it to simplify your code?

Comment: Sir, I am new into Javascript. I have not learned JQuery yet. The reason behind the use of JQuery is just because it is mentioned in the bootstrap link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were missing `index` while fetching element inside `markNotes`:

```
function markNotes(index) {
   let notes = localStorage.getItem("notes");
   if (notes != null) {
    notesObj = JSON.parse(notes);
   } else {
    notesObj = [];
   }
  let noteCard = document.getElementsByClassName("noteCard")[index];
    noteCard.style.color = "lightblue";
    console.log("Color is applied")
   localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notesObj));
   //showNotes(); you don't need to add this again
}
```

complete working code fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/narkhedetusshar/25hvr3ej/5/)