# Unable to change DOM element style that is pass as a string

Tags: javascript, dom, bootstrap-4, styles, getelementsbyclassname

I have passed my DOM element as a string here.

```
function showNotes() {
    let notes = localStorage.getItem("notes");
    if (notes != null) {
        notesObj = JSON.parse(notes);
    } else {
        notesObj = [];
    }
    let html = "";
    notesObj.forEach(function(element, index) {
        html += `<div class="noteCard card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Title: ${element.title}</h5>
          
          <p class="card-text">${element.text}</p>
          <a href="#" id="${index}"onclick="deleteNotes(this.id)" class="card-link" >Delete Note</a>
          <a href="#" id="${index}"onclick="markNotes(this.id)"class="card-link">Important</a>
        </div>
      </div>`;

    });
```

I want to give a style to the card. When an user clicks the link "Important" (as mentioned in the DOM), the corresponding card color should be changed. So I am trying to access the "noteCard" class.
Here is my markNotes() function

```
function markNotes(index) {
    let notes = localStorage.getItem("notes");
    if (notes != null) {
        notesObj = JSON.parse(notes);
    } else {
        notesObj = [];
    }
    noteStyl = document.querySelectorAll('.noteCard')[0];
    noteStyl.style.color = "red";
    console.log("Color should be applied")
    localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notesObj));
    showNotes();
}
```

I have tried the following things also but nothing works out.

```
noteStyl = document.getElementsByClassName('noteCard')[0]
noteStyl = document.querySelector('.noteCard')[0];
```

With this code, when I am clicking the link "Important" nothing is going to change except the printing of "Color should be applied".
So there must be a problem in accessing the DOM file. I am really stuck in it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: off-topic: `document.querySelector('.noteCard')` would achieve the same as `document.querySelectorAll('.noteCard')[0]`

Comment: `noteStyl` will always be the first "card" regardless of the link you click.

Comment: So how to put the command in the corresponding cards? When I clicked the link "Important" whether in first card or any card no color change occurs only the console() executes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below code and comments I added I commented your localStorage code and added my dummy code for demo.

```js
function showNotes() {
  let notes = [{
      title: 'title1',
      text: 'text1'
    },
    {
      title: 'title2',
      text: 'text2'
    },
    {
      title: 'title3',
      text: 'text3'
    }
  ];

  notesObj = notes;
  /* if (notes != null) {
      notesObj = JSON.parse(notes);
  } else {
      notesObj = [];
  } */
  let html = "";
  notesObj.forEach(function(element, index) {
    html += `<div class="noteCard card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Title: ${element.title}</h5>
          
          <p class="card-text">${element.text}</p>
          <a href="#" id="${index}"onclick="deleteNotes(this.id)" class="card-link" >Delete Note</a>
          <a href="#" id="${index}"onclick="markNotes(this.id)"class="card-link">Important</a>
        </div>
      </div>`;

  });
  document.getElementById("html").innerHTML = html; // to insert data into HTML

}

showNotes() // calling function first time

function markNotes(index) {
  console.log('index', index)
  /*let notes = localStorage.getItem("notes");
  if (notes != null) {
    notesObj = JSON.parse(notes);
  } else {
    notesObj = [];
  }*/
  noteStyl = document.querySelectorAll('.noteCard')[index];
  noteStyl.style.color = "red";
  console.log("Color should be applied")
  localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notesObj));
  //showNotes(); // See I have commented this code
}
```

```html
<div id="html">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man. I got my mistake. I have modified  `noteStyl = document.querySelectorAll('.noteCard')[0]` to `noteStyl = document.querySelectorAll('.noteCard')[index];` and got everything right. I have forgot to pass the parameter of the function "markNotes". Sir, I want a little bit more help from you. Could you please review my whole code at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62984663/unable-to-access-the-dom-which-i-passed-as-a-string-how-to-do-it-by-using-exter] and help me in how to make appear the search by clicking on the search button? Again I am thankful to you.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with accessing the DOM. I think you are trying to access an element that is not on the page.

Are you displaying the `html` on the page at the end of `showNotes` function?
You can do so by: `someDiv.innerHTML = html`.

## Update

to access a specific card (not always the first one) maybe you can set an id for each card with its index example: `card-${index}`, then accessing it with `.getElementById`

## Update #2

You are storing `notesObj` as an array, and in the loop (in `showNotes`) you are creating a static style. So you need to update the object styles in `notesObj`

So instead of setting the style, create a styles object:

```js
function markNotes(index) {
    let notes = localStorage.getItem("notes");
    if (notes != null) {
        notesObj = JSON.parse(notes);
    } else {
        notesObj = [];
    }
    if(!notesObj[index].styles) notesObj[index].styles = {};
    notesObj[index].styles.color = "red";
    localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notesObj));
    showNotes();
}
```

Then apply it in the `showNotes`:

```js
notesObj.forEach(function(element, index) {
        style = "";
        if(element.styles) {
            console.log(element.styles);
            for (let key in element.styles) {
                style += `${key}: ${element.styles[key]}`;
            }
        }
        console.log(style);
        html += `<div class="noteCard card" style="width: 18rem; ${style}">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Title: ${element.title}</h5>
          
          <p class="card-text">${element.text}</p>
          <a href="#" id="${index}"onclick="deleteNotes(this.id)" class="card-link" >Delete Note</a>
          <a href="#" id="${index}"onclick="markNotes(this.id)"class="card-link">Important</a>
        </div>
      </div>`;

    });
```

Comment: No sir, I am not displaying the HTML on the page rather this DOM element is displayed as  a card. Here is the full question with the entire code, PLease go through it once [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62984663/unable-to-access-the-dom-which-i-passed-as-a-string-how-to-do-it-by-using-exter]

Comment: I guess he wants to change the style on click of important @BalabhadraChand isn't it?